# MP3 files are cut short when played on a car infotainment system

Tags: audio, mp3

I've noticed a strange behavior with some of my MP3 music files that are on a SD Card.

When these files are played by VLC or Windows Media Player on a PC, they work fine.
However, when played by the infotainment system of a car (a Mk VII Golf in this case), the displayed duration time is shorter by about 30 seconds, and by consequence the song is cut before the end.

On Windows, examining these MP3 files via File Explorer, *Properties -> Details -> Length* displays the full duration of the music clip.
However, Mp3 Tag Tools shows the shortened duration in the "Length" attribute (both in ID3v1.1 and ID3v2.x).

This happens with all the MP3 files of some albums; all other albums are played correctly.  Perhaps the culprit is the software I used to rip the MP3 files from my (legally bought) CDs. I'd like to know the cause of the problem and how it can be fixed.

Comment: Try removing the id tags, play it on the car system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does it happen?** Often, audio or video files will have an ID3 Tag containing their length. For example, if I have a song one minute long, there is a bit of text, usually at the very beginning of the file, which says its length is a minute long. Not all MP3s have this, but most do, and the ID3 Tags are created by the software which created the MP3. This is what you were seeing when you used Mp3Tag.

Now, this might seem redundant at first, but the reason for this is so that if the file is uploaded to the web, audio players will know the length of the MP3 before it is finished downloading, meaning the media player knows what percentage of the song has downloaded, and can show an accurately long seek bar while the file is still streaming; you can know the song's length before you have the entire song and can check the length yourself.

If you've ever downloaded MP3s before, you'll notice that sometimes, the length of the MP3 according to the media player keeps increasing as more and more of the MP3 loads. This happens when an MP3 lacks the ID3 Tag containing its length (or said ID3 Tag is at the end of the file instead of at the beginning) , and the media player keeps increasing the seek bar's length to accommodate for newly downloaded data.

However, this does mean that if you're using an MP3 encoder which doesn't calculate the length of the MP3 correctly, the length ID3 Tag will be different than the MP3's actual length. Most well programmed media players, such as Windows Media Player or VLC Player ignore the length ID3 Tag, opting instead to find the length of the MP3 automatically since the file is being played offline anyway. In the case of your car's MP3 Player, however, it's most likely that for whatever reason it always obeys the length of the MP3 according to the ID3 Tag, and the ID3 Tag is incorrect thanks to whatever audio ripper you were using.

**So what's the solution?** You have a few options. You could try a different CD ripper - I'm sure plenty more exist - or if you're particularly drawn to the CD ripper you're using now, you could try repairing the MP3 by converting it to its own format. I'd recommend the former option, however. If you use [RealPlayer](http://real.com) , it has a CD ripper built in which can rip to MP3 that you could try instead. If you'd prefer the latter option, you'll probably have some minor quality loss, but for a simple audio converter you could try [Freemake Audio Converter](http://www.freemake.com/free_audio_converter/) . Just click and drag your MP3 into the main area of the application, choose to convert to MP3 at the bottom, and for the quality, choose "Same as source" and use the resulting converted file.

Comment: Thanks.  I've solved the problem by importing each MP3 file into Audacity and re-exporting it as MP3 again.